# Access nginx from local network

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, http

I have nginx running on ubuntu and PHP and can access it remotely at example.com.  I am doing some development work and which to access it from another machine on the same network, and ideally would like to use port 443.  I partially got this working using static IP 10.120.11.110, but would like to do so using example.com.  How can this be accomplished?

```
server {
    server_name example.com 10.120.11.110;
    root /var/www/facdocs/api/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/facdocs-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/facdocs-error.log;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS,POST, PUT,PATCH, DELETE";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization";
    add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Origin";
    add_header Access-Control-Max-Age "3600";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Link';
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php8.1-fpm-facdocs.sock;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php8.0-fpm-facdocs.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }
    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    if ($host = 10.120.11.110) {
        return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by me
    server_name example.com 10.120.11.110;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

```
michael@michael-HP-EliteBook-830-G5:~$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:e8:2c:b0:58:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.120.11.110/24 brd 10.120.11.255 scope global noprefixroute enp0s31f6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f296:5072:9bd8:39a5/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:46:11:c1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.120.11.109/24 brd 10.120.11.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp1s0
       valid_lft 6168sec preferred_lft 6168sec
    inet6 fe80::9d5d:d33:f846:7e4b/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
michael@michael-HP-EliteBook-830-G5:~$
```

```
C:\Users\michael>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Unknown adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 10:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8858:36cc:61b1:8e67%8
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.120.11.101
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.120.11.1

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

C:\Users\michael>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add on the computer in the LAN that you want to access your website from the following line: `10.120.11.110   example.com` to */etc/hosts* (or *C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts* if on Windows)

Comment: Thanks!  Easier than I expected.  Also, while I didn't need the Window's solution, nice having them both in one answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Hosts file is a lot of work if you have multiple hosts (e.g., Classroom environments or you don't have enough rights to do so).

An easier and faster way to accomplish this is to use https://nip.io/, you don't have to do anything in the hosts file **just your nginx config has to be altered from example.com to 10-120-11-110.nip.io.**

You can access then with this url in your browser (10-120-11-110.nip.io) directly without hostfile entries. nip.io has some other examples on its site if you're curious.

This Makes testing of virtual hosts painless.